# Send data from bootstrap x-editable

Tags: java, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, servlets, x-editable

How can I send data from bootstrap x-editable to the servlet? Currently my setup is like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('a.accordion-toggle').editable({
        ajaxOptions: {
            dataType: 'json'
        }, 
        placement: 'right',
        name: 'toEdit',
        url: '../admin/module_edit.do',
        title: 'Edit'
    });
});
```

and my servlet is like this:

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/admin/module_edit", method = RequestMethod.POST )
public @ResponseBody
String editSubjectAndStrand( @RequestParam
String toEdit, HttpServletRequest request )
{
    System.out.println( toEdit );
    return "";
}
```

It didn't now print anything in my server side. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not returning `JSON` from your controller it is returning `String`.

Comment: @Jai Yes. I was just testing if the editable is sending data to my controller. The `System.out.println( toEdit );` doesn't print anything in the console. Seems that it doesn't even call my controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the error. I should also define `pk` for it to send ajax request to the server. The [documentation](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html) help me to solve this. In the documentation there is this part:

> Main attributes you **should** define are: 
>   **type** - type of input (text, textarea, select, etc) 
>   **url** - url to server-side script to process submitted value (/post, post.php etc) 
>   **pk** - primary key of record to be updated (ID in db) 
>   **id** or **name** - name of field to be updated (column in db). Taken from id 
>   or data-name attribute 
>   **value** - initial value. Usefull for select, where value is integer key of text to be 
>   shown. If empty - will be taken from element html contents