# DataTables with x-editable not sending ajax data

Tags: javascript, datatables, x-editable

I'm trying to make a datatable editable with x-editable plugin.
Everything works well but the sending of edited datas. When I click the cell, editor is opening, but nothing is sent to the backend.

This is my code. here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrSo/cLb4xvwt/).

```
// DataTables
let isDataTables = document.getElementById('dataTable');
if (isDataTables !== null) {
    $.extend( true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
        dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-3'B><'col-sm-3'l><'col-sm-3'f><'col-sm-3'r>>" + "<'row'<'col-sm-12't>> " + "<'row pad10top'<'col-sm-6'i><'col-sm-6'p>>",
        //serverSide: true,
        select:true,
        stateSave: true,
        pagingType: "full_numbers",
        scrollY:    "60vh",
        scrollCollapse: true,
        pageLength: 50,
        responsive: {
            details: false
        }
    } );
}
$('#dataTable').DataTable( {    
    "drawCallback": function(){
        $.each ($("#dataTable td"), function (i, v) {
            tmp_pk = $(this) .closest($('tr')).attr('id');
            $(this).attr('data-pk', tmp_pk);
        });

        //let api = this.api();
        //$('.editable', api.table().body())
        $('td.controle').editable({
            url : '/response',
            pk: tmp_pk,
            ajaxOptions: {
                type: 'put'
            }
        })
    },
} );
```

Comment: I found the answer here : [send-data-from-bootstrap-x-editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19925984/send-data-from-bootstrap-x-editable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the answers to my question in the FAQ:

> Data is not submitted to server! Why? The most possible reason is that
>   you have empty pk or url options. If you want to submit data without
>   pk please set send option to "always".
>
> Also form is not submitted if you did not change value. To manage this
>   behavior see savenochange option.

https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/faq.html

Comment: thanks for the tip, for me , i had also to move data-pk to the parent div